# How to calculate atypical object volume

Tags: volume

I am not a mathematician but a simple programmer and came across a situation where I have to calculate different kinds of object volume. There is no specific type of object and i found that there are [dozen of formulas to calculate volume](http://www.math.com/tables/geometry/volumes.htm) like

1. Cube $= a^3$
2. Rectangular prism $= a b c$
3. Irregular prism $= b h$
4. Cylinder $= b h = π r^2 h$
5. Pyramid $= \dfrac13 b h$
6. Cone $= \dfrac13 b h = \dfrac13 π r^2 h$
7. Sphere $= \dfrac43 π r^3$
8. Ellipsoid $= \dfrac43 π r_1 r_2 r_3$

and maybe many more. **But** is there any general formula exists that can calculate the volume of any type of object?

Comment: There do exist a general formula, i.e. $V=\iiint_D\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$, but…

Comment: @user302797 another horrible formula but ...?

Comment: … but of no practical use if one wants to get a value from it, unless using Monte-Carlo.

Comment: It depends on how the object is specified, of course. As a programmer, you surely understand that one cannot write a program if one does not know what data structure the input is in! That said, if the shape is given as a polyhedron, you can use [a certain sum over the faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume).